# Difference between Oracle jdbc driver classes?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using Oracle's `ojdbc5.jar` and noticed that it includes two JDBC driver classes.

What is the difference between `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` vs. `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`?

Which one should I use in my Java project?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> For Oracle 9i onwards you should use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver rather than oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver as Oracle have stated that oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is deprecated and support for this driver class will be discontinued in the next major release.

-- [http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,*9i*&_10g](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g)

Comment: See also: [Oracle JDBC Drivers release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production README](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/111070-readme-083278.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/package-summary.html)

"*Your code should use the package oracle.jdbc instead of the package oracle.jdbc.driver used in earlier versions of Oracle. Use of the package oracle.jdbc.driver is now deprecated, but will continue to be supported for backwards compatibility.*"