# Hibernate doesn't want to load Oracle driver

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I downloaded Hibernate 4.1.2 and am using Oracle Database 10g Release 2. The JDBC driver I am using is `ojdbc14.jar`.

I set up HibernateUtil class as:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }catch(HibernateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

In `hibernate.properties` I have:

```
hibernate.dialect org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.username HR
hibernate.connection.password HR
hibernate.connection.url jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
```

But Hibernate doesn't want to load the driver. It throws an exception saying 'No appropriate driver found'.

I tried to load the driver with `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` and it works fine.

Comment: Should properties not be separated by an `=` character?  I.e. `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` etc?

Comment: @mcfinnigan, good point but in the exception I see 'no suitable driver for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe' so it looks like it is reading the file fine.

Comment: hmm.  Are you sure that the oracle jar is on the classpath?

Comment: Yes. I can load it through `Class.forName`.

Comment: Is this a web application? If so, are you *positive* that the oracle jarfiles are loaded and on the classpath when Hibernate is started?  That's the only other possibility I can think of.

Comment: What if you add `Class.forName(...)` before construction of `Configuration`?

Comment: @axtavt if I do as you suggest everything is working fine but I want to make Hibernate load the driver.

Comment: @Martin: It looks like Hibernate doesn't see `hibernate.connection.driver_class` property. Make sure that it's spelled correctly and you don't override it in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in using the wrong JDBC Oracle driver. When I tried with `ojdbc6.jar` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- Try to make the properties file valid by putting *=* between key and value
- Check that there aren't any trailing spaces after the values
- Use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`. See [Difference between Oracle jdbc driver classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes) for further reference.

Comment: By the way, properties file is valid, but this syntax is rarely used, therefore it's quite surprising.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter whether I use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` or `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: Can you add the full Hibernate stacktrace to your post?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection URL is configured wrongly, should be:

```
hibernate.connection.url jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

More information for Oracle's URL can refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/urls.htm).

As other answer point out:

Use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter whether I use `...@localhost:1521:xe` or `...@localhost:1521/xe`. As I said through JDBC I am able to connect with exactly the same settings.