# Cannot find or load oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have installed Oracle 11.2 and Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

In the command line, if i try to:

```
java oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Java says: impossibile to load or find oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I have copied `ojdbc5.jar`, `ojdbc6.jar` and `ojdbc6_g.jar`

From `oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\jdbc\lib` to
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib`

If i run `echo %CLASSPATH%` I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib (ie where I have copied the jar files)
```

Any reasons why Java can't find `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You reference a folder on the classpath and expect it to load all jars in it. That is not how the classpath works, you need to reference specific jars (and normally you should **NOT** put third party jars inside the JDK folder).

It is also important to know that the `CLASSPATH` is usually ignored by java applications, except for the most basic use cases.

You can do what you try to achieve by doing:

```
java -cp <path-to>\ojdbc7.jar oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

This will fail btw because `OracleDriver` has no `public static void main(String[] args)` method and therefor cannot be run like this. The normal way to use a JDBC driver is to have the driver on the application classpath, and simply specify the right driver URL. JDBC 4.0 (Java 6) or higher compliant drivers will be automatically loaded from the classpath (as specified with `-cp`, the `Class-Path` manifest entry etc).

On an unrelated note, `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is considered deprecated, use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead, see [Difference between Oracle jdbc driver classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes)

Comment: The problem is that I need OracleDrive within a JSP page... (Eclipse > Dynamic Web Project)

Comment: That is a different question, I'd suggest to search around a bit or ask a new question. Just a hint: you usually define a `DataSource` in the application server, request it through JNDI (or dependency injection) and get a `Connection` from it; in that case the driver is placed in the classpath of the application server itself, not of the web app. If you really need it in the webapp without a `DataSource`, it needs to be in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the application. Also, it usually is a design/architecture smell when a database is queried directly on a JSP

Comment: I have opened a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723147/java-eclipse-package-oracle-jdbc-driver-does-not-exist but none seems able to help

Answer (score 1):

Putting a directory on the classpath doesn't put all the jar files within that directory on the classpath. It's not clear why you've copied the Oracle jar file into your Java installation directory - I'd recommend *not* doing that - but you should just list the location explicitly. For example, if you've copied it into the `lib` directory relative to your application, you could use:

```
java -cp lib\ojdbc7.jar;. your.class.Name
```

You *can* use `*` in a `-cp` command line argument to find all jar files, e.g.

```
java -cp lib\*;. your.class.Name
```

or you *could* copy it into an "extensions" directory - but I think it's clearer to be explicit.

Comment: `-cp lib\oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` won't work (it isn't a jar)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Whoops - c'n'p issue. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem and this is what i did
I extracted ojdbc5.jar and then i copied oracle folder in extracted ojdbc5.jar and then pasted in current location where i wrote jdbc program ( not mentioning the directory as it differs from programmer to programmer), then used import oracle.jdbc.*; statement in my jdbc program as oracle.jdbc has OracleDriver in it.
Rest of the program is same

Answer (score 0):

Before copying `ojdbc6.jar` to `<jdk-home>/jre/lib/ext/`, in IDEA you need to add the `ojdbc6.jar` file in "Structure" -> "SDK" -> "add classpath" to `<jdk-home>/jre/lib/ext/ojdbc6.jar`