# Java-Eclipse: Package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have Java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

And Oracle `11.2` with Windows 8

I am trying to run a Dynamic Web Project from Eclipse. All works fine until I try to:

```
    DriverManager.registerDriver(
        new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()
    );
```

Then it says:

```
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /showUser.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package oracle.jdbc does not exist
```

I have added (As an external JAR) the ojdbc file (ojdbc7.jar):

[image]

But still java isn't able to find the `package oracle.jdbc`.

My .jsp is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>

    <%-- Set the scripting language to java and import the java.sql package --%>
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" %>

    <%
      try {
        // Load Oracle Driver class file
        DriverManager.registerDriver(
            new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()    // <---- ERROR HERE!
        );
           ...
    %>
```

I have googled many other questions but the solution is far from clear! What exactly should I do to correctly include `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` ?

### Spec

java version "1.7.0_25"
Oracle 11.2
Windows 8 (64bit)
Eclipse Kepler

Comment: Did you put the jars inside `WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: Why do you have five(!) different versions of the driver in your build path. That doesn't make sense

Comment: Remove all drivers you don't need (**especially** the deprecated ones for Java 1.4 and Java 1.5) and only keep `ojdbc7.jar` as you are using Java 7. (btw: `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` has been deprecated for years, you should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`)

Comment: Ok, I have left only ojdbc7.jar. I have renemade it to new `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()` but the same error appears: `package oracle.jdbc does not exist` (i have updated the question)

Comment: See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IFKr0.png

Comment: redeploy the application

Comment: Now it is working ! I have added the ojdbc7.jar in the Tomcat/lib directory!

Answer (score 0):

Try put the jars under the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it: I had to put ojdbc7.jar in the Tomcathome/lib directory

And I had to manually run the server with TomCat:

[image]