# No data in combobox while retrieving from database

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, combobox

```
<select name="qualification">
   <%
     Connection con=null;
     Statement st=null;
     ResultSet res;
     try{
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE","system","123");
       st=con.createStatement();
       res=st.executeQuery("select qualification from course");
       while(res.next()){
         String qualification = res.getString("qualification");
  %>
      <option value="<%=qualification%>"><%=qualification%></option>
  <%
      }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {    out.print(e);
    }
 %>

</select>
```

Here I am trying to display values in the combox box, but the combobox shows empty in the output!
My db table has just two fields, name and qualification with enough values.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the server logs (tomcat or whatever?)

Comment: No error ! Code works fine..but the comboxbox is yet empty. Table has enough values to be displayed.

Comment: did you check the html code rendered (view source, inspect element)?

Comment: Oh..it shows classNotFoundException though everything is been set up correctly !

Comment: It can't. You can't argue with a `classNotFoundException`. What class is not found (My guess: Oracle driver)

Comment: Yes
Exception occurred : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Comment: have a look here (besides original oracle docs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701610/cannot-find-or-load-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
 }catch(Exception e)
{    out.print(e);
}
```

Outputs the error into your html where it's hard to find. Consider logging full stacktrace into server-log as well

```
 }catch(Exception e) {    
   e.printStackTrace ();
   out.print(e);
 }
```

As you mentioned in comment you see a class not found for the oracle driver - make sure to add ojdbc6.jar (or ojdbc7.jar) into your WEB-INF/lib or into your tomcat/lib folder (or similar depending on your servlet engine)