# I am trying to connect to oracle database in an RCP Application and I am getting the following error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, eclipse-rcp, rcp

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver cannot be found by Application.app_1.0.0.qualifier. In an RCP application. Can anyone please suggest what different steps I may need to include.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find or load oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701610/cannot-find-or-load-oracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  It is good practice to do some initial searching for your issues, as there are many hits on it in google

Comment: My question is specific to RCP Eclipse application. I am able to connect to the jdbc driver for simple java application.

Comment: Found a solution                                                                                             
1. Add the jdbc jar to MANIFEST.MF -> Runtime -> Classpath -> Add -> jar file 
2. Save the MANIFEST.MF
3. Build and re-run the Application