# SpringBoot error: Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation

Tags: spring-boot

I am learning SpringBoot and I just tried running my project which used to run successfully, but now this error pops up

```
 enter cod2018-08-25 11:30:21 WARN  c.z.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2018-08-25 11:30:24 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connectione here
```

after this couple of exceptions are thrown like..

```
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
```

**application.properties:**

```
   #server
server.port=7003

#database
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:Xe
spring.datasource.username=XXXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

#logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
logging.level.=INFO

#eureka-guidelines
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:7005/eureka
spring.application.name=SupplyManagement_14_SpringBoot
```

**Pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp.supplyManagement</groupId>
    <artifactId>SupplyManagement_14_SpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SupplyManagement_14_SpringBoot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I tried some debugging, like
1. manually checking oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is there or not.
2. using other ojdbc's like 6.
3. maven updates.

But nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have no Idea why, But I restarted my System and now it works fine.

Answer (score 101):

Regarding the warning message from the question's title :

> Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation

That is because you used the **wrong value** for `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`.

Use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

See detailed answer here: [Difference between Oracle jdbc driver classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes/6202721#6202721).

Answer (score 24):

You must use **`oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`** instead of **`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`** in POM file

Comment: in `application.properties`, not POM

Answer (score 0):

It clearly indicates driver is missing, please check maven local repository, look for jdbc driver jar file in XX:\user\XXX\m2\XX

From oracle web [site](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) to connect with Oracle 12 using JDK 8 you can follow this..

```
<groupid>com.oracle.jdbc</groupid>
<artifactid>ojdbc8</artifactid>
<version>12.2.0.1</version>
```

Comment: I have checked it the ojdbc jar is there. Also my normal jdbc stuff is wotking with the help of this jar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this dependency to get the Oracle JDBC driver was not found on Maven repository.

So, better review POM for this dependency. FYI, the oracle doesn't post the latest JDBC driver in Maven repository. If you wish to get the latest JDBC driver from the Oracle database installation folder (**${ORACLE_INSTALLATION}/jdbc**) or download it from Oracle Technology Network website. You may refer to this link if you are using 12c version:

> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html

Then, you need to create new folder to locate your Oracle JDBC driver inside your project and change the dependency for Oracle JDBC by pointing it into the folder you just create.

Comment: I knew maven wont keep the jar file for me. Thats why i did it manually and placed the jar file at the local maven repo, but as of now it doesnt work.

Comment: Please try to change it by following this link:  http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project

Comment: Gunardy Sutanto I used the first method stated in your link. I have directly added it to the ojdbc7 folder so the path is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to check whether the DB is up and running, try to make a ping to the database, check if the port is up. If this is ok then check POM and application.properties in spring project and finally handle the error so the code alert of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question, straight from horse's mouth

[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/package-summary.html)

"*Your code should use the package oracle.jdbc instead of the package oracle.jdbc.driver used in earlier versions of Oracle. Use of the package oracle.jdbc.driver is now deprecated, but will continue to be supported for backwards compatibility.*"