# Apache NiFi not able to connect to Oracle 12c using ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc8.jar

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-nifi

We are trying to connect to an Oracle 12c database from Apache NiFi. But it simply does not work:
We get the following error:

```
bdc2314a-669e-1e85-875c-73b035db9ba5
ExecuteSQL[id=bdc2314a-669e-1e85-875c-73b035db9ba5] Unable to execute SQL select query select * from ETSETTRA.APB where rownum < 10 due to java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@//osiXXXX:1521/UTSOFTP'. No FlowFile to route to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@//osiXXXX:1521/UTSOFTP
```

The configuration is as follow,. and I have tried a lot of other combination

[image: Driver Configuration]

This should be straight forward?

Full stack trace

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@osi3454:1521/UTSOFTP'
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:474)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor701.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:222)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@osi3454:1521/UTSOFTP'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2224)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:470)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2216)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why not use the JDBC driver?

Comment: Which one is that, when I search, this is the only one popping up on Oracle home page. I suppose it is the JDBC driver

Comment: @user1700737, please provide the full stacktrace from the log file

Comment: I have done that above

Comment: Is the jar in the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I think the driver name is not correct:

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

vs.

oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

[Difference between Oracle jdbc driver classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202653/difference-between-oracle-jdbc-driver-classes)

Comment: Makes no difference

Comment: @user1700737 If it makes no difference, then probably you don't have the driver on your classpath.